# Regex: Replace any string other than a known fixed string? (delimited by quotes)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

I'm trying to match and replace strings of the form

`mystring = "string-text"`

with

`mystring = "XYZ string-text"`

*if and only if* string-text is not equal to `red`. For example

```
original-text             replacement
-------------             -----------
mystring = "red"          mystring = "red"
mystring = "green"        mystring = "XYZ green"
mystring = "blue"         mystring = "XYZ blue"
mystring = "reds"         mystring = "XYZ reds"
mystring = "_red"         mystring = "XYZ _red"
mystring = "1ed"          mystring = "XYZ 1ed"
mystring = "ree"          mystring = "XYZ ree"
mystring = ""             mystring = "XYZ "
mystring = "12345678"     mystring = "XYZ 12345678"
```

`mystring = "red"` is left untouched and all others are replaced as described. Does there exist a regular expression to achieve this?

The best I could manage is

```
^mystring = "(?!red)(.*)"$
```

The capturing group `(.*)` allows replacement to be printed with `mystring = "XYZ \1"`. This works in most cases but fails for the testcase `mystring = "reds"`

Comment: What's the language?

Comment: I've just been testing in Notepad++ and https://regexr.com/, I was hoping it should be transferable to C# (but thought I'd deal with that separately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is slightly hacky, but you can include the ending quotation mark in the lookahead then in the actual match pattern:

```
^mystring = "(?!red")(.*)"$
```

Where the substitution is:

```
mystring = "XYZ $1"
```

[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/33Lp3J/1).

Answer (score 3):

You can include the `"` in the lookahead, and  use `mystring = "XYZ \1` in the replacement including matching the last `"`

```
^mystring = "(?!red")(.*")$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yPAX3j/1)

Or using 2 capture groups

```
^(mystring = ")(?!red")(.*")$
```

And replace with `\1XYZ \2`

---

**Note** that if you are using C#, the capture group notation is `$1` instead of `\1`

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/Mu4rXw) with the replacement.

Comment: it seems to work, but doesn't feel natural somehow (I'll need to think it over I guess)... out of interest, is there no way to match 'not red' as an expression by itself?

Comment: are 3 quotes necessary by the way `^mystring = "(?!red")(.*)$` seems to do something silmilar. Thanks a lot for the swift reply, this is definitely good progress

Comment: There are other patterns you could use, but it will involve the string `red` as you want to avoid that specific string.

Comment: @RobHoff You could do that, but the double quote at the end `"$` means that there should be a double quote present. If you omit that, you can also have a match like this https://regex101.com/r/5N18zo/1

Comment: Yes I see, I saw the failing test case `mystring = "hello` when the last quote isn't included given in the link in @code's answer

Comment: @RobHoff I have added a C# demo for the replacements.